# Merging two Lists of objects based on an attribute

Tags: c#, performance

I have this class defined:

```
public class DocumentSearchResult
    {
        public string RowCount { get; set; }
        public string TotalRows { get; set; }
        public Int64 DocumentQueryExecutionTimeMS { get; set; }
        public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
        public string DocumentSize { get; set; }
        public string DocumentAuthor { get; set; }
        public string DocumentDescription { get; set; }
        public string DocumentFileExtension { get; set; }
        public double DocumentRank { get; set; }
        public Int64 DocumentDocId { get; set; }
        public Int64 DocumentWorkId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentWrite { get; set; }
        public string DocumentParentLink { get; set; }
        public string DocumentLastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string DocumentFileType { get; set; }
        public string DocumentSummary { get; set; }
        public string DocumentLibrary { get; set; }

        //These next set of properties are used for Viewing the results in embedded or preview
        public string DocumentRedirectedEmbededURL { get; set; }
        public string DocumentRedirectPreviewURL { get; set; }
        public string DocumentRedirectURL { get; set; }
        //These two properties are needed to show how the results were gathered MetaData-Content and the folder path location in Ember of the file
        public string SearchSource { get; set; }
        public string FolderPath { get; set; }
```

I get data from two different sources and fill in this class with the appropriate information.  Now the client wants the option to include both sets of data and return one response eliminating duplicates, and the other option is to find the matching records from one list that are in the other list and return only the items that appear in both lists.  So the first option is an AND merge to include all results from both lists but don't show duplicates.  The other is an OR merge where the results must be in both lists trimming all records that don't match.

So to merge the list or combine the list I created this function:

```
public List<DocumentSearchResult> StitchMetaDataAndContent(List<DocumentSearchResult> metaDataResults, List<DocumentSearchResult> contentResults, bool merge = false)
    {
        if (merge)
        {
            List<DocumentSearchResult> stitchedContent;
            stitchedContent = metaDataResults.Union(contentResults).ToList();
            foreach(DocumentSearchResult docX in stitchedContent)
            {
                docX.RowCount = (metaDataResults.Count + contentResults.Count).ToString();
            }
            return stitchedContent;
        }
        else
        {
           metaDataResults.RemoveAll(x => !contentResults.Any(y => y.DocumentName == x.DocumentName));
            foreach(DocumentSearchResult docX in metaDataResults)
            {
                docX.RowCount = metaDataResults.ToString();
            }
            return metaDataResults;
        }
    }
```

For the merge portion I use the Union operator to merge the content into the results.  This appears to be working, but I am having problems stripping out the duplicates.  I need to strip the duplicates based on the DocumentName property for both sets.  This is the only data in the record that is guaranteed to be identical between the two sets.

In the second it appears the RemoveAll is working using the DocumentName (I continue to test this to make sure), and stripping all the files in the metaDataResult list that aren't in the contentResults list, but I am concerned this will slow as the lists increase.  It is possible that the metaDataResults could be 10,000 and I know that some searches on the contentResults can be over 150K results.  Is the RemoveAll the best approach to this?  Is there a quicker way someone can point me to that may speed up performance?

Thanks.

Comment: May be try to use Dictionary<string, DocumentSearchResult>, where string is document name. Then for the merge, foreach via secondary results and only add a record if no key exists in the primary search results.

For the second portion do the same -- foreach loop with removal if they key exists in another dictionary. That should be faster, I believe, because Dictionary uses hashes to access elements/find keys.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I'll begin to look at this as a solution.